# There is a table having country and city columns as shown in the below table input. I need the output as mentioned below

Tags: sql, select, unpivot

[image]

[image: **enter image description here**]

I need a SQL query to get the desired output from the input table

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, postgresql...?

Comment: You should be handling this in your presentation layer (e.g. PHP), _not_ in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `UNION` query, first selecting the distinct country names, and then each of the cities for that country. The output is then ordered by the country; whether the value is a country or a city; and then by the value:

```
SELECT DISTINCT country AS data, country, 1 AS ctry
FROM cities
UNION ALL
SELECT city, country, 0
FROM cities
ORDER BY country, ctry DESC, data
```

Output:

```
data    country     ctry
India   India       1
BNG     India       0
CHN     India       0
HYD     India       0
Sweden  Sweden      1
GOTH    Sweden      0
STOCK   Sweden      0
VAXO    Sweden      0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/81NWCTVCsftDiErfgjJg3u/1)

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like you are willing to interleave the records, with each country followed by its related countries.

The actual solution heavily depends on your datase, so let me assume that yours supports window functions, row constructor `values()` and lateral joins (SQL Server and Postgres are two candidates).

In SQL Server, you could do:

```
select distinct rn, idx, val
from (
    select t.*, dense_rank() over(order by country) rn
    from mytable t
) t
cross apply (values (t.country, 1), (t.city, 2)) as v(val, idx)
order by rn, idx, val
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d08d91ed44c57cdad77b77fe43df425a)**:

```
rn | idx | val   
-: | --: | :-----
 1 |   1 | INDIA 
 1 |   2 | BNG   
 1 |   2 | CHN   
 1 |   2 | HYD   
 2 |   1 | SWEDEN
 2 |   2 | STOCK 
 2 |   2 | VAXO
```

In Postgres, you would just replace `outer apply`  with `cross join lateral`: **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=df9fa5a2269b1db1279ef088718553e9)**.

Comment: i guess the first select needs a distinct to not repeat india 3x

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: indeed... answer update (with assumptions on the database OP is using).